# Wordpress custom permalinks using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Currently I added custom structure for posts premalinks `/post/%post_id%` through permalinks settings in Admin.

Since I need to rewrite permalinks for categories, tags and author pages as follow:

**Categories**

Current `/post/category/category_name` to `/category_name`

**Tags**

Current `/post/tag/tag_name` to `tag/tag_name`

**Author**

Current `/post/author/author_username` to `/author/author_username`

I tried to create custom RewriteRule in .htaccess, which didn`t work at all:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ ./post/category/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/tag/([^/]*)$ ./post/tag/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/author/([^/]*)$ ./post/auhtor/$1 [L]
```

Any help with .htaccess rules coding to achieve such permalinks is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you not tried anything?

Comment: @MikeRockett so far http://pastebin.com/4uDvZMn3 but didn`t work for me.

Comment: Your `RewriteRule`s are backwards.

Comment: @AndrewCheong you mean it should RewriteRule ./post/category/([^/]*)$ ^/$1 [L] instead?

Comment: Doesn't WordPress handle category and tag permalinks? If I'm not mistaken, it has options for "category base" and "tag base". Not sure about author though. (Note: I don't use WordPress at all, and so this is me jogging my memory.)

Comment: And no, the rules are not backwards in terms of this purpose. Where did you put those rules? (Nonetheless, you would still need to ensure that WordPress outputs the correct URIs for this to work.)

Comment: PS: I see there's a plugin for author slugs: http://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/

Comment: @MikeRockett included in .htaccess, not the add rewrite rule https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule and the permalinks in admin panel is so limited and have no author structure.

Comment: it seems you should either do external redirects or redirect internally to index.php

Comment: Ihab, what you want is to go to /category_name and ge the category archive you'd normally get at /post/category/category_name, right? And without using add_rewrite_rule

Comment: @yivi It is clear that I need to rewrite the three types of archives: category, tags and author as mentioned not just the category type ;)

Comment: Could you please update your question with a screenshot of your configuration from `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` when you're logged in as an admin ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I only added value for post page as mentioned above, both category and tag are empty.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice that. Well, i could easily provide you some rules to do what you want but i expect some conflict with Wordpress and i don't think that'd be a good solution

Comment: Ihab, doesn't the answer by Nick help you? To more clearly understand what you need to accomplish...

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you have rewrite engine on in your apache configuration
2. Login to your WordPress with administrative rights and go to Settings -> Permalinks as shown into attached three images.
   [image]
3. If permalink is not updated, then you don't have write access to root of website or rewrite module of apache is not enabled.
4. If permalink message appears, it means it also created .htaccess in the root of WordPress site.

This way you can achieve following url formats:

Categories

```
category/category_name
```

Tags

```
tag/tag_name
```

Author

```
/author/author_username
```

> Note: it is always best practice to prefix url so for category,
>   /category prefix should be added into path rather than directly
>   accessing it because wordpress have page and post which are accessed
>   directly without any prefix generally.

Comment: Well buddy, here the purpose is to make it work even if one has to follow abc of WordPress. I personally tested it on my desk and it worked exactly same as described above.

Comment: Not sure why this recieved a down vote. The author clearly did not specify that he had tried in the admin and this is a well put together answer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test with WordPress, but with http://htaccess.mwl.be/

You were pretty close:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /post/category/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)$ /post/tag/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]+)$ /post/author/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test with WordPress, but with http://htaccess.mwl.be/

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ ./post/category/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/tag/([^/]*)$ ./post/tag/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/author/([^/]*)$ ./post/auhtor/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: if this .htaccess file doesn't work , please check in <?php phpinfo(); ?>. mod_rewrite is already enable or not. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing a pretty high-performance Project, i would strongly suggest noch to mess around with the Wordpress standard .htaccess and instead use Wordpress internal functions to accomplish the same task. Despite a cleaner Project this would also make your solution Webserver agnostic (who knows if you want to switch to NGINX or something else in the future).

Wordpress main function that should help you quite a bit is [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). As an example your category link could look like that:

```
  // place this rule inside function.php
  add_action("init", function() {
      add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
  });
```

Though you should bear in mind, that the regex should have exceptions for other 'top-level' objects.

*An important note from the wordpress docs:*
After adding new rules you have to flush the rules table: From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

There is also a plugin called [Rewrite](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/screenshots/) available. As it has not been updated for a long time, i would not suggest using it in Production, but its code could server as a source of inspiration.

Comment: I use default structure /?cat=$id so, modifying rule to index.php?cat=$matches[1] didn`t work. When tried /$id i redirected to home index.php. Any suggestions?

Comment: my regex was faulty. fixed it now.