# Permalink redirects to localserver

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I used permalink to redirect to a post page when a post is clicked. It works fine on local server. But even after hosting to the main server, it gets redirected to the local server page when clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="blog-post_item">
    <h4 class="text-center"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress custom permalinks using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824697/wordpress-custom-permalinks-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Export your database as `.sql` open the file using text editor. find the `http://your.local.url` and replace with `http://your.new.url` and again import it. This will work.

If you find any permalink error anymore, try this: Fix permalinks (Optional)

If you experience that you get a 404 error when you try to open links on your site, the Permalinks are broken. Luckily it is very easy to fix this.

Log in to your WordPress dashboard.
Click Settings and then Permalinks
Scroll down and click Save Changes.
[image]